# Merge images with CSS to single image for Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a series of images I've layered together using CSS but I want to display the result in Discord though Node.js but I can only load one image in a rich embed so I need to find a way to take the layered images and dynamically create a single image that I can load into Node.js.

here's a quick sample of the many layers

```html
echo '<div style="position: relative; width: 150px; height: 300px;">';
     if ($ConditionRLeg <= 75){echo '<img src="PaperDoll\Black_Adjustments\NekollxComm_BaseV2LegS2Bandaged_1_Black.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20px; width:200px;">';}
     if ($ConditionRLeg <= 50){echo '<img src="PaperDoll\Black_Adjustments\NekollxComm_BaseV2Legs2Bandaged_2_Black.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20px; width:200px;">';}
     if ($ConditionRLeg <= 25){echo '<img src="PaperDoll\Black_Adjustments\NekollxComm_BaseV2LegS2Bandaged_3_Black.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20px; width:200px;">';}
     echo '<img src="PaperDoll\Black_Base\NekollxComm_BaseV2LegS2_Black.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -20px; width:200px;">';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: maybe these can help you https://github.com/jankuca/dom-panda https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

Comment: webshot seems to have worked https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot
but it creates a local image file, which is fine but now i cant find how to load that local imange in discord.js RichEmbed() Any thoughts?